# How do i add multiple objects to NSMutableArray and how do i retrieve my objects properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Super basic questions, which i'm having problems with.

1. How do i add multiple objects to my `NSMutableArray`? (Now i only add one with `self.itemsArray[0] = iPhoneItem;` )
2. How do i retrieve for the first objects property (itemName)?

I have a calss: Item - which looks like follows.

*Item.h*

```
@interface Item : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *itemTitle;

- (id)initWithItemTitle:(NSString *)aTitle;

@end
```

*Item.m*

```
@interface Item ()

@end

@implementation Item

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.itemTitle = aTitle;
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

And now i just want to create a few objects, add them in to an `NSMutableArray` and retrieve the itemTitle property.

*ViewController.m* - (.h has no additional changes from standard "create singel view application"

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *itemsArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    Item *iPhoneItem = [[Item alloc] initWithItemTitle:@"iPhone"];
    Item *iPadItem = [[Item alloc] initWithItemTitle:@"iPad"];
    Item *macBookPro = [[Item alloc] initWithItemTitle:@"MacBookPro"];

    self.itemsArray[0] = iPhoneItem;

    NSLog(@"%@", self.itemsArray[0].itemTitle); //How would i do this?
}

@end
```

Best regards, iOS-rookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check iOS reference, no need to ask questions: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:

Anyway, here is an example:

```
[itemsArray addObjectsFromArray: @[obj1, obj2]]; //adding multiple objects
((Item *)[itemsArray firstObject]).itemTitle //get title of your object
```

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. I thought this was the place for questions about coding?

Comment: It is, but you can at least try to read API reference first;) Doesn't matter, I hope answer helped.

Comment: @getJETsetTER Also you don't have to cast when accessing the properties of an object retrieved from the array. [itemsArray firstObject].itemTitle is enough... or [[itemsArray firstObject] itemTitle]

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to access properties for an object in an array directly like :
      self.itemsArray[0].itemTitle

It is cleaner to:
        Item *iPhoneItem = (Item*)[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", iPhoneItem.itemTitle);

Also keep in mind that you can use [itemsArray firstObject]; and [itemsArray lastObject];

Comment: - the cast is not necessary